# Periodicity in noisy data and the usefulness of differencing

Tags: time-series, frequency, sparse

Disclaimer: I don't have great stats knowledge.

I'm doing some exploratory data analysis with the goal of detecting whether or not there is periodicity in the data set. I have a collection of photon arrival times and associated spatial locations (i.e. a 2d image with times that each photon hit). The data has two principal components that contributed to it: uniform random noise and an unknown number of weak point source signals. Think a grainy, low-light image with faint pulsing lights.

The weak signals are:

- Unknown in number.
- Are randomly distributed in the image.
- Have different periods, but are on the same order of magnitude.
- Have different phases.
- Sparse, the time between source photon arrivals are many, many periods apart.
- The time profile is Gaussian, but it's possible to only get a few (or none) photons per cycle.

Although it would be nice, I'm not necessarily interested in finding the individual source periodicities. Rather, identifying that there are likely periodic sources in the image is enough for a first step.

I have found [some](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/379244) [astronomical](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1992ApJ...398..146G) papers that seem to deal with this in pulsar searches. (Any others are welcome!)

One thing I was wonder that I can't find any papers on is if working with the spatial and temporal differences in the data set gives any useful information. Say for every photon I take the spatial difference between every other.

$\Delta r_{n} = r_{i} - r_{j} $ for all $i, j$

And similarly for the associated times,

$\Delta t_{n} = t_{i} - t_{j} $ for all $i, j$

It seems that the point processes will cause an excess of low-valued $\Delta r_{n}$'s compared to the null case of no point processes in the image. Is there a statistical test or technique I can do to test this?

More importantly, would there be an analogous effect for the $\Delta t_{n}$'s ? Will this differenced data set have anything useful that could be tested for? I.e. clustering at certain values or a periodogram that has more power than just the original, non-differenced times?

Thanks.